# Cannot get functions to execute

Tags: php, html

So if the last function ended up working. And I followed all of your instructions to the T, why is this function not working properly? I've looked over it for an hour, tried rewrite it over and over again and all I get is a 0 or no return.

```
function marketing () {
$newsold = $_POST['newsold'];
$usedsold = $_POST['usedsold'];
$carsSold = $newsold + $usedsold;
$AdSpend = $carsSold * 275;
echo "You shoud spend roughly $AdSpend per year on advertising";
}

marketing();
```

Comment: I also tried adding a POST method and it did not work.

Comment: You're missing a close-curly-brace on the function makeProfit().

Comment: The first thing you should really be doing is checking the PHP logs.

Comment: You've made a number of functions, but called none of them.

Comment: I tried calling them directly under the functions like: adSpend();

Comment: You'd be better not to remove the original question for those coming by later.  I have updated my answer to consider your edit.  You just have a variable name problem.

Comment: you can't echo the way like that, it doesn't work. see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You echo the values inside the function:

**not**:

`echo "$autoProfit";`

**but**,

```
<?php
function autoProfits () {   
$usedprofit = 1527;
$newprofit = 800;
$newsold = $_POST['newsold'];
$usedsold = $_POST['usedsold'];
$uprofit = $usedsold * $profitused;
$nprofit = $newsold * $profitnew;
$autoProfit = $uprofit + $nprofit;
}
autoProfits();

?>
```

Take close att with the curly brace where to be placed.

Comment: This is wrong.  Variables will still be interpreted inside of double quotes.  If they were single quotes, you would be correct.  Also, you removed the echo, so this will output nothing.

Comment: how do you understand function in php. the autoProfits() show the result without echoing it

Comment: if the OP needs to echo the autoProfits(), @JeanGkol's script then works.

Comment: 1. It's a common misconception that double-quotes around a variable will not echo correctly.  This will work fine: echo "$autoProfit";
2. JeanGkol has removed the echo from the autoProfits() function.  Hence his function will neither return nor echo anything.
3. Jean's variable names are still wrong, so even if he re-added the echo, it would still echo 0 every time.

Comment: yes, it's accepted. btw, where's the other source of the OP's? is that all?

Comment: each of variables has no couple in calculation. that makes me confused how the OP wrote the function.

Answer (score 1):

Several things with your code:

1) By default, a form will post with GET and not POST.  So either change your PHP variables to $_GET OR change your form's method to $_POST.  I prefer to change the method.

```
<form action="calc.php" method="POST">
```

2) You're missing a curly brace on your function:

```
function makeProfit () {
  if ($profit >=0) {
    echo "Your company is making a profit.";
  } else {
    echo "Your company is not making a profit.";
  }
}
```

3) In your function adSpend(), you should invert the line for $carsSold.

4) You have used upper and lower-case characters interchangeably in your variable names ($usedSold vs $usedsold).  PHP variables are case-sensitive.

5) The "+" operator when used to combine a string and integer may work, but it would be better not to put integers in quotes.

5b) Using a comma will cause PHP to not recognize your variable as a number, so use $profitUsed = 1527; instead of $profitUsed = "1,527";

6) Your variables at the top of a PHP file are not GLOBAL.  You'll either need to convert them to global variables, or (I prefer) send them as parameters to your function.  An example of the corrected adSpend():

```
function adSpend ($newSold = 0, $usedSold = 0) {
  $adSpendPerCar = 275;
  $carsSold = $newSold + $usedSold;
  $adSpend = $carsSold * $adSpendPerCar;
  echo $AdSpend;
}

adSpend($newSold, $usedSold);
```

7) Finally, when you expect an integer from user input, you'd be best to verify that you have an integer.  There are a lot of ways to do this, one simple method is to do something like this:

```
$newSold = intval($_POST['newsold']);
$usedSold = intval($_POST['usedsold']);
```

**Edit** Change your variables $profitused for $usedprofit and $profitnew for $newprofit

```
function autoProfits () {   
  $usedprofit = 1527;
  $newprofit = 800;
  $newsold = $_POST['newsold'];
  $usedsold = $_POST['usedsold'];
  $uprofit = $usedsold * $usedprofit;
  $nprofit = $newsold * $newprofit;
  $autoProfit = $uprofit + $nprofit;
  echo $autoProfit;
}
```

Comment: the OP needs to echo the autoProfits(), it couldn't be set like that way inside the curl brace

Comment: For sake of good practice, I have removed the double quotes around my echo.  The code is fully functional as I have tested it on my local server.

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeProfit () {
  if ($profit >=0) {
      echo "Your company is making a profit.";
  } else {
      echo "Your company is not making a profit.";
  }
}
```

This function is missing the last '}' (curly bracket)

But you should also be sure when calling adSpend(), that the variables you're trying to access is set, else you won't get anything out of it.

Since you've made that setup, then you should be calling the functions right after you've set all the variables, for anything to work.

Answer (score 0):

You're using undefined variables on the products. You defined $usedprofit and $newprofit but you're multiplying $profitused and $profitnew. Since they're not defined, PHP assumes they're 0.